# ASP.Net Get New Selected Item From DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have an Menu Form.
In the end of the Form, I have a dropdownlist to set is the Menu is still available or not.
If it not available, then I choose disabled in dropdownlist

When editing the availability of the menu, I set Selected Value on *Page_OnLoad* to a certain value corresponding to the Menu current availability with code:

```
disabled.Items.FindByValue(isDisabled).Selected = true;
```

Lets say the menu is *Disabled*. The selected value of the dropdownlist is Disabled.

Then I changed it to Enabled and click save, on my Button_Onclick Event

```
isDisabled = disabled.SelectedItem.Value;
```

I get this error

> cannot have multiple items selected in a dropdownlist.

How to proceed to get new value of dropdownlist?

- Should I clear the selected item first? +

  - I've try `dropdownlist.ClearSelection`. But I only get the first value.
- Should I using OnSelectedIndex Change on dropdownlist?

  - Can I avoid this? As I should set AutoPostBack to true and it'll kinda refresh the page. I
    know I can set `if(!IsPostBack)` on *Page_OnLoad*, but if possible, i want to avoid refreshing
    the page.

Answer (score 0):

The select element has a name attribute. This is used as the key for any selected value(s) when a form is submitted. You can access the value by passing the key as an indexer to the Request.Form collection:

var number = Request.Form["number"];

Comment: I've try it. It gives me `cannot have multiple items selected in a dropdownlist` error because I've set selected item on load